# NullPointerException at deployment of EAR at Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, ear, weblogic12c

We move our Application from Weblogic 9.2 to Weblogic 12.1.2. Deploying the EAR using Admin Console fails due to an not documented NullPointerException. After searching a lot for this stacktrace and Error message, we found very little. [One OTN Thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3527605) with similar topic pointed to the doubling of JARs within Weblogic Classpath and EAR. So we searched for JAR doubling in Weblogic Installation and EAR. The EAR has packed xml-apis-1.3.02.jar and WL Classpath includes xml-apis.jar. After removing xml-apis-1.3.02.jar from EAR and a new deployment, we faced the same NullPointerException again.

[The stacktrace of the Exception](http://pastebin.com/Ur6S0DAt)

Ingredients of the EAR:

- APP-INF/lib

  - activation-1.1.jar
  - annotations.jar
  - aopalliance-1.0.jar
  - barcode4j.jar
  - commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
  - commons-codec-1.6.jar
  - commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
  - commons-compress-1.5.jar
  - commons-digester-2.1.jar
  - commons-io-2.2.jar
  - commons-lang-2.6.jar
  - commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
  - core_bg_common.jar
  - core_bg_server.jar
  - core_bg_server_ejb.jar
  - core_common.jar
  - core_server.jar
  - core_server_ejb.jar
  - dom4j-1.6.1.jar
  - domain-1.0.jar
  - ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar
  - itext-2.1.7.jar
  - jasperreports-4.1.1.jar
  - java-image-scaling-0.8.5.jar
  - jaxb-api-2.1.jar
  - jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
  - jcommon-1.0.15.jar
  - jdtcore-3.1.0.jar
  - jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
  - jmf-2.1.1e.jar
  - joda-time-1.6.jar
  - libsqlite4java-linux-amd64.so
  - libsqlite4java-linux-i386.so
  - mail-1.4.1.jar
  - mybatis-2.3.5.jar
  - opencsv-2.3.jar
  - poi-3.9.jar
  - poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
  - poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
  - spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
  - sqlite4java-win32-x64.dll
  - sqlite4java-win32-x86.dll
  - sqlite4java.jar
  - standard-1.1.2.jar
  - stax-api-1.0-2.jar
  - swiftgantt-0.4.0.jar
  - swing-layout-1.0.3.jar
  - synthetica.jar
  - wadl-core-1.1.jar
  - xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
  - xmlenc-0.52.jar
  - xz-1.2.jar

Thats what comes with Weblogic:

- aether-api-1.13.1.jar
- aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar
- aether-impl-1.13.1.jar
- aether-spi-1.13.1.jar
- aether-util-1.13.1.jar
- ant.jar
- ant.jar
- ant-all.jar
- ant-all.jar
- ant-antlr.jar
- ant-antlr.jar
- ant-apache-bcel.jar
- ant-apache-bcel.jar
- ant-apache-bsf.jar
- ant-apache-bsf.jar
- ant-apache-log4j.jar
- ant-apache-log4j.jar
- ant-apache-oro.jar
- ant-apache-oro.jar
- ant-apache-regexp.jar
- ant-apache-regexp.jar
- ant-apache-resolver.jar
- ant-apache-resolver.jar
- ant-apache-xalan2.jar
- ant-bootstrap.jar
- ant-bootstrap.jar
- ant-commons-logging.jar
- ant-commons-logging.jar
- ant-commons-net.jar
- ant-commons-net.jar
- ant-contrib.jar
- ant-jai.jar
- ant-jai.jar
- ant-javamail.jar
- ant-javamail.jar
- ant-jdepend.jar
- ant-jdepend.jar
- ant-jmf.jar
- ant-jmf.jar
- ant-jsch.jar
- ant-jsch.jar
- ant-junit.jar
- ant-junit.jar
- ant-junit4.jar
- ant-launcher.jar
- ant-launcher.jar
- ant-netrexx.jar
- ant-netrexx.jar
- ant-nodeps.jar
- ant-starteam.jar
- ant-stylebook.jar
- ant-swing.jar
- ant-swing.jar
- ant-testutil.jar
- ant-testutil.jar
- ant-trax.jar
- ant-weblogic.jar
- asm-3.1.jar
- bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar
- cieCfg_common_rcu_lib_12.1.2.jar
- cieCfg_common_svctbl_lib_12.1.2.jar
- com.bea.core.apache.commons.collections_3.2.2.jar
- com.bea.core.apache.commons.lang_2.7.0.jar
- com.bea.core.binxml_1.7.0.0.jar
- com.bea.core.i18n_2.1.0.0.jar
- com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans_2.2.0.0_2-5-1.jar
- com.bea.core.xquery.xmlbeans-interop_1.7.0.0.jar
- com.bea.core.xquery_1.7.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.comdev_7.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config_8.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config_8.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-owsm_8.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-quickstart-launcher_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-quickstart-schema-launcher_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-security_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-security_8.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-security-impl_8.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-wls_8.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-wls-online_8.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.config-wls-schema_12.1.2.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.dependency_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.encryption_2.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.oui_1.3.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.rcu_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.service-table_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.service-table-impl_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.service-table-schema_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.wizard_7.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.cie.xmldh_2.6.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.executor-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.persistence-service-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.persistence-service-provider-state-management-impl_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.state-management-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.state-management-provider-aggregate-impl_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.state-management-provider-coherence-impl_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.state-management-provider-common-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.state-management-provider-jdbc-impl_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.state-management-provider-memory-impl_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.state-management.transactional-map-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.weblogic.sca.engine_3.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.audit-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.disi-impl_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.disi-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.fabric-common-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.logging-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.mdds-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.mdds-jersey-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.orasaaj-rt-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.orawsdl-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.session-manager-impl_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.session-manager-internal-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.user-api_12.1.2.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-ws-api_2.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-ws-metainf-services_2.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.ws-databinding-api_3.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.ws-databinding-impl_3.0.0.0.jar
- com.oracle.webservices.ws-star-impl_1.0.0.0.jar
- com.sun.istack.istack-commons-runtime_2.13.jar
- com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver_20050927.jar
- com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-core_2.2.jar
- com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-impl_2.2.jar
- com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-jxc_2.2.jar
- com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-xjc_2.2.jar
- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.FastInfoset_1.2.12.jar
- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.saaj-impl_1.3.jar
- com.sun.xml.stream.buffer.streambuffer_2.2.jar
- com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-eclipselink-plugin_2.2.jar
- com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt_2.2.jar
- com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-tools_2.2.jar
- com.sun.xml.ws.policy_2.3.1.jar
- com.sun.xml.ws.sdo-eclipselink-plugin_2.2.jar
- commonj.sdo_2.1.1.jar
- commons-cli-1.2.jar
- cryptoj_5_0.jar
- dms.jar
- eclipselink.jar
- fmwgenerictoken.jar
- glassfish.el_1.1.0.0_2-2.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
- javax.annotation_1.1.0.0_1-1.jar
- javax.ejb_3.2.0.jar
- javax.jms_1.1.3.jar
- javax.jsp_3.0.0.0_2-2.jar
- javax.mail_1.1.0.0_1-4-4.jar
- javax.management.j2ee_1.1.0.0.jar
- javax.persistence_2.0.0.0_2-0.jar
- javax.persistence_2.1.0.0_1-0-2.jar
- javax.servlet_2.1.0.0_3-0.jar
- javax.xml.bind_2.2.4.jar
- javax.xml.rpc_1.2.3.jar
- javax.xml.stream_1.1.1.0.jar
- javax.xml.ws_2.3.0.jar
- javax-xml-bind.jar
- javax-xml-ws.jar
- jersey-client-1.17.1.jar
- jersey-core-1.17.1.jar
- jersey-json-1.17.1.jar
- jersey-multipart-1.17.1.jar
- jersey-server-1.17.1.jar
- jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar
- jettison-1.1.jar
- jsr250-api.jar
- jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
- maven-aether-provider-3.0.4.jar
- maven-artifact-3.0.4.jar
- maven-compat-3.0.4.jar
- maven-core-3.0.4.jar
- maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar
- maven-model-3.0.4.jar
- maven-model-builder-3.0.4.jar
- maven-plugin-api-3.0.4.jar
- maven-repository-metadata-3.0.4.jar
- maven-settings-3.0.4.jar
- maven-settings-builder-3.0.4.jar
- mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.22-bin.jar
- oauth-client-1.17.1.jar
- oauth-server-1.17.1.jar
- oauth-signature-1.17.1.jar
- ojdbc6.jar
- ojdbc6_g.jar
- ojdbc6dms.jar
- ojdl.jar
- ojdl2.jar
- ojmisc.jar
- ons.jar
- oracle.http_client_12.1.2.jar
- oracle.http_client_oracle.http_client_12.1.2.jar
- oracle.toplink.wls_12.1.2.jar
- oracle.ucp_11.2.0.jar
- oracle.webservices.base.wls.classpath_12.1.2.jar
- oraclepki.jar
- orai18n.jar
- orai18n-collation.jar
- orai18n-lcsd.jar
- orai18n-mapping.jar
- orai18n-net.jar
- orai18n-net-ee.jar
- orai18n-servlet.jar
- orai18n-tools.jar
- orai18n-translation.jar
- orai18n-utility.jar
- orapki.lib_12.1.2.jar
- org.apache.ant.patch_2.0.0.0_1-8-4.jar
- org.apache.ant.patch_2.1.0.0_1-7-1.jar
- org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2-api_3.1.1.jar
- org.codehaus.woodstox.woodstox-core-asl_4.1.2.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.nosql.jar
- org.glassfish.external.management-api_3.1.0.b001.jar
- org.glassfish.gmbal.gmbal-api-only_3.1.0.b001.jar
- org.glassfish.ha.ha-api_3.1.0.b001.jar
- org.glassfish.metro.metro-cm-api_2.3.jar
- org.glassfish.metro.metro-cm-impl_2.3.jar
- org.jvnet.mimepull.mimepull_1.9.jar
- org.jvnet.staxex.stax-ex_1.7.1.jar
- osdt_cert.jar
- osdt_core.jar
- plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
- plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar
- plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
- plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
- plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
- plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
- sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
- sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
- sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
- sisu-inject-plexus-2.3.0.jar
- svctbl_jmx_client_12.1.2.jar
- toplink-dataservices.jar
- toplink-dataservices-web.jar
- toplink-grid.jar
- wagon-file-2.2.jar
- wagon-http-2.2-shaded.jar
- wagon-provider-api-2.2.jar
- weblogic.jaxrs.client_2.0.0.0.jar
- weblogic.jaxrs.internal.common_1.1.0.0.jar
- weblogic.jaxrs.server_2.0.0.0.jar
- weblogic.server.modules.portable_12.1.2.0.jar
- wldb2.jar
- wldcw.jar
- wldcw_de.jar
- wldcw_es.jar
- wldcw_fr.jar
- wldcw_it.jar
- wldcw_ja.jar
- wldcw_ko.jar
- wldcw_pt_BR.jar
- wldcw_zh_CN.jar
- wldcw_zh_TW.jar
- wlinformix.jar
- wlsqlserver.jar
- wlsThirdPartyJdbcDrivers.jar
- wlsybase.jar
- wltbh.jar
- wltbh_de.jar
- wltbh_es.jar
- wltbh_fr.jar
- wltbh_it.jar
- wltbh_ja.jar
- wltbh_ko.jar
- wltbh_pt_BR.jar
- wltbh_zh_CN.jar
- wltbh_zh_TW.jar
- wlupg.jar
- wlupg_de.jar
- wlupg_es.jar
- wlupg_fr.jar
- wlupg_it.jar
- wlupg_ja.jar
- wlupg_ko.jar
- wlupg_pt_BR.jar
- wlupg_zh_CN.jar
- wlupg_zh_TW.jar
- xercesImpl.jar
- xml-apis.jar
- xmlmesg.jar
- xmlparserv2_jaxp_services.jar
- xmlparserv2_sans_jaxp_services.jar

Comment: Please show us the relevant logfile entries, including the full stacktrace for the NPE.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [The Stacktrace of the NullPointerExeption on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ur6S0DAt)

Comment: Decompiled StatefulSessionManager.class using Jad to find out where the NPE comes from. It seems there is cache or swapper null. Both are initialized by public void setup(BaseEJBRemoteHomeIntf, BaseEJBLocalHomeIntf, BeanInfo, Context, EJBCache)
Is it a bug?


    public void undeploy()
    {
        super.undeploy();
        cache.clear();
        cache.stopScrubber();
        swapper.destroy();
    }

Comment: I was running into a similar issue (but other libraries) where Weblogic 12.1.1 and 12.1.2 was not successfully deploying EARs. I was searching for a solution and at the only way to solve it was to update to Weblogic 12.1.3. It has other deployment issues (EJB cache issues), these ones are solvable. Is the bug mentioned below fixed then? (see cpurdy's answer)

Answer (score 1):

First, I do not believe the exception you have pasted is the "real" error but is rather a symptom of another error. It is failing to activate the change, i.e. install your .ear file. That exception is not helpful. If I had to guess there is another error somewhere in the logs. Generally duped jars on the classpath will cause a `NoClassDefFoundError` or a `ClassNotFoundException`. Check for those.

Second, if you are having classes conflict between your deployments and the default weblogic classpath, you can try adding this to your weblogic.xml to force it to use the libraries in your ear:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>package.that.conflicts.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll log a bug on this to make sure it's looked at. You should never get an NPE.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide the bug id?